# javascript: how to return function dynamically from an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an SDK with javascript, using the standard object pattern. It works perfectly, unless I want to dynamically configure one of the resultant objects, e.g. if its demo use a simple RNG, if its a real game, use a HW RNG (different RNG implementation).  Below does not work:

sdk.js

```
var Sdk = (function () {
    var rng;
    var localRng = (function() {
        var getInt = function(min, max) { // min and max included 
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }
        return {
            getInt: getInt
        }
    })();

    var init = function(demo=true) {
        if (demo ) {
            console.log("initiing sdk as demo");
            rng = localRng;
        } else {
            console.log("ALERT, REAL not implemented")
        }
    };
    return {
        init:init,
        rng:rng,
    }
})();
```

main.js

```
  sdk.init(true);
  var start = sdk.rng.getInt(1,12);
```

The problem is that sdk.rng is undefined.

If I hard code it thus:

```
    var rng = (function() {
        var getInt = function(min, max) { // min and max included 
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }
        return {
            getInt: getInt
        }
    })();
```

in the above it works.

The crux is that you can play a game in demo mode or real mode, so it has to be possible to switch how the SDK does stuff under the hood (i.e. which object it uses, the demo one or real one). Obviously in the real sdk, and the real rng, there are a lot more functions, both private and public (returned)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
return {
    init:init,
    rng:rng,
}
```

you're returning an object whose `init` property points to the current reference of `init` (which is the function), and whose `rng` property points to the current reference of `rng` (which is `undefined`). It sounds like you'd want to *dynamically* return a reference to the local variable `rng` instead, which can be done by making the returned object's `rng` property a *getter* which returns that local variable:

```
return {
    init:init,
    get rng() {
      return rng;
    }
}
```

```js
var sdk = (function () {
    var rng;
    var localRng = (function() {
        var getInt = function(min, max) { // min and max included 
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }
        return {
            getInt: getInt
        }
    })();

    var init = function(demo=true) {
        if (demo ) {
            console.log("initiing sdk as demo");
            rng = localRng;
        } else {
            console.log("ALERT, REAL not implemented")
        }
    };
    return {
        init:init,
        get rng(){
          return rng;
        }
    }
})();
sdk.init(true);
var start = sdk.rng.getInt(1,12);
console.log(start);
```

Rather than reassigning the variable, though, you might consider just saving a reference to the returned object, and assigning to a property of it when `init` is called:

```js
var sdk = (function () {
    var rng;
    var localRng = (function() {
        var getInt = function(min, max) { // min and max included 
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }
        return {
            getInt: getInt
        }
    })();

    var init = function(demo=true) {
        if (demo ) {
            console.log("initiing sdk as demo");
            returnedObj.rng = localRng;
        } else {
            console.log("ALERT, REAL not implemented")
        }
    };
    const returnedObj = { init };
    return returnedObj;
})();
sdk.init(true);
var start = sdk.rng.getInt(1,12);
console.log(start);
```

Comment: Your fist solution worked like a charm.  I would never have guessed that the get keyword work here, or that you would not need something like sdk.rng.get().getInt(1,12).